# Calculating the most likely next outcome based on previous outcomes and % on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, probability

Alright, so i'm doing this as a pet project.

Is there a way for me to get excel to calculate the most likely **next** outcome based on the probability of each outcome (in percentages) along with a list of previous outcomes?

So basically, instead of spitting out numbers based on the % of it happening, it want to get a number based on the % and the previous outcomes.

I've been trying to look around for this on google, but I haven't really been able to find a way to do it. Would I need to use VBA? If so, could someone point me to a what exactly I would need to do so that i can go read up on it?

Comment: It's a very open question... Which one is your input and the expected output? For example, have you got just values? values and probability?...

Comment: You could start off with formulas to get your bearings. The countif function can be used to find the incidence of an outcome in a list of outcomes, and counta can give you the total number of outcomes.